# Reproducir archivos .opus en Swift 3-4

Tags: ios, swift

Buenas, mi pregunta es como podría reproducir un archivo .opus desde mi aplicación en swift, el archivo esta remoto en un servidor y tendría que coger ese archivo y reproducirlo en la aplicación, como podría hacer? ya que lo he intentado de todas las maneras y no hay forma de que funcione

```
func escucharCancion(){
    let url = URL(string: "http://solivellaluisalberto.000webhostapp.com/prueba.opus")

    do {
        let audioData = try Data(contentsOf: url!)
        try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(data: audioData)
        audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    } catch {

    }
}
```

El problema es que al ser .opus no carga la canción, pero cuando es .mp3 si que funciona perfectamente.

No no he echo debug, pero se que el fallo es al intentar pasar a Data el archivo .opus, cuando es .mp3 si que se pasa a Data correctamente desde la URL, pero con el .opus no funciona

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La librería MobileVLCKit viene bien en este caso, esta en Objective - C pero no deberías tener problemas al usar los métodos.

[Documentación MobileVLCKit](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/MobileVLCKit/2.2.1/)

[Link de Descarga](http://nightlies.videolan.org/build/iOS/)

Primero [configura tu proyecto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift) para trabajar las clases de obj-c en tu proyecto swift 3.

1.- Crear VLCMedia con el contenido de tu URL:

```
var instanciaVLCMedia: VLCMedia = VLCMedia().mediaWithURL("url")
```

2.- Utiliza las funciones de reproducción con VLCMediaPlayer o VLCMediaList

```
var instanciaVLCMediaList: VLCMediaList = VLCMediaList().initWithOptions(nil)

instanciaVLCMediaList.playMedia(instanciaVLCMedia)
```